# MySQL Unknown column 'XXXXX' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, join

I'm getting this MySQL Inner Join query error and, although I have tried very hard to figure out, I can't figure out where the bug is.

```
SELECT db_trailer_id.*, db_trailer_locs.* 
FROM db_trailer_id INNER JOIN db_trailer_locs 
ON db_trailer_id.id = db_trailer_locs.trailer_id 
WHERE db_trailer_id.vin = XXXXXX
```

Tables and field names have been checked and double checked.

**db_trailer_id**

- id
- vin

**db_trailer_locs**

- id
- trailer_id
- location

Is there something missing in the syntax?  Is it because I'm trying to match to a column in the first (parent) table?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does `XXXXXX` actually appear in your query?

Comment: I'm actually using a sprintf() so actually %s, but I've tried with a physical paramter as well.

Comment: @RichardOwens You should quote your values, else it will be considered as columns. Added answer.

Comment: $query_trailerStatus = sprintf("SELECT db_trailer_id.*, db_trailer_locs.* FROM db_trailer_id INNER JOIN db_trailer_locs ON db_trailer_id.id = db_trailer_locs.trailer_id WHERE db_trailer_id.vin = %s", $vin);

Comment: Thanks @Soolie - I'll try it now.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote your values, else it will be considered as columns:

```
SELECT `db_trailer_id`.*, `db_trailer_locs`.* 
FROM `db_trailer_id` INNER JOIN `db_trailer_locs` 
ON `db_trailer_id`.`id` = `db_trailer_locs`.`trailer_id` 
WHERE `db_trailer_id`.`vin` = 'XXXXXX'
```

Would recommend adding backticks, but totally your wish.

Comment: If the OP is using a prepared statement, then he should _not_ have to worry about quoting positional parameters.  Rather, the statement handles this automatically.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yea, just otherwise, would like to highlight.